# Como crear tabla dinámica con angular

Tags: angular

estoy tratando de crear una tabla dinamica con angular desde un *OBJECT ARRAY*
ya me salio la parte de la cabecera pero para pintar el resultado tengo que utilizar diferentes.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let item of config.cab" class="punt-cab">{{item}}</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody> 
         <tr *ngFor="let item of config.anio">
            <td  class="punt-comp">{{item}}</td> 
        </tr>  
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

que me devuelve el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Embargo tengo otros objeto que debo colocar en el OBJECT ARRAY, para pintar una columna puse utilice el ANIO,al colocar otro `<td>` se agrega mas filas pero no la columna pero para el siguiente tengo que utilizar los otros array de forma dinamica

esto es lo que he intentado:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of config | keyvalue">
            {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
        <!-- {{item.value | json }}  
            {{item.value[0]}} -->
            <!-- <td    class="punt-comp">{{item.value}}</td>    -->
        </tr>    

<tr *ngFor="let item of config.anio">
            <td    class="punt-comp">{{config.anio.split(",")}}</td>   
             
        </tr>
```

**este es el OBJET ARRAY que estoy consumiendo**

```
{
   "anio":[
      "enero",
      "febrero",
      "marzo",
      "abril",
      "mayo",
      "junio",
      "julio",
      "agosto",
      "septiembre",
      "octubre",
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   "puntBase":[
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   "salCarte":[
      1500,
      1500,
      1500,
      1500,
      1500,
      1500,
      1500,
      1500,
      1500,
      1500,
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   "stockCar":[
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   "efec30a0":[
      "20%",
      "20%",
      "20%",
      "20%",
      "20%",
      "20%",
      "20%",
      "20%",
      "20%",
      "20%",
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   "efec1a31":[
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   "formExtr":[
      15,
      15,
      15,
      15,
      15,
      15,
      15,
      15,
      15,
      15,
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   "digitali":[
      1,
      1,
      1,
      1,
      1,
      1,
      1,
      1,
      1,
      1,
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   "deseSoci":[
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   "ro":[
      0,
      1,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   "cab":[
      "FECHA",
      "PUNTOS BASE",
      "SALDO CARTERA",
      "STOCK CLIENTES",
      "-30 A 0",
      "1 A 30",
      "FORMA EXTRA",
      "DIGITAL",
      "DESEMPEÑO",
      "RIESGO OPE",
      "AMONESTACIONES",
      "",
      ""
   ]
}
```

**Quisiera que cada array se pinte en cada columna de la tabla dinamicamente, OJO PUEDE VENIR MAS CAMPOS O MENOS CAMPOS**

Comment: Yo veo que usando otra etiqueta <tr> ya lo tendrías solo que apuntas en el 'of' al subarray que quieres o te refieres a pintar todo con un solo <tr>?

Comment: @Isanchezo podrias responder la respuesta por favor ?

Comment: @Isanchezo usando eso me crea una fina nueva

Answer (score 1):

Yo crearía un modelo para envasar los elementos:

```
export class DynamicTable {
  anio!: string;
  puntBase!: string;
  salCarte!: string;
  stockCar!: string;
  efec30a0!: string;
  efec1a31!: string;
  formExtr!: string;
  digitali!: string;
  deseSoci!: string;
  ro!: string;
  cab!: string;

  constructor(anio: string, puntBase: string, salCarte: string, stockCar: string, efec30a0: string, efec1a31: string
, formExtr: string, digitali: string, deseSoci: string, ro: string, cab: string) {
  this.anio = anio;
  this.puntBase = puntBase;
  this.salCarte = salCarte;
  this.stockCar = stockCar;
  this.efec30a0 = efec30a0;
  this.efec1a31 = efec1a31;
  this.formExtr = formExtr;
  this.digitali = digitali;
  this.deseSoci = deseSoci;
  this.ro = ro;
  this.cab = cab;
 }
}
```

En el componente conseguiría el objeto que más elementos tenga y entonces crear un array de DynamicTable:

```
config: any;
objects!: DynamicTable[];
objectKeys = Object.keys;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.objects = [];
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.http.get('../../assets/config.json')
    .subscribe(arg => {
      this.config = arg;
      console.log(this.config);
      let maxObject = Math.max(this.config.anio.length, 
      this.config.puntBase.length, this.config.salCarte.length,
      this.config.stockCar.length, this.config.efec30a0.length, 
      this.config.efec1a31.length,
      this.config.formExtr.length, this.config.digitali.length, 
      this.config.deseSoci.length,
      this.config.ro.length, this.config.cab.length);
      console.log(maxObject);
      for (let i = 0; i < maxObject; i++) {
        let anio = (this.config.anio[i] != undefined) ? 
        this.config.anio[i] : '';
        let puntBase = (this.config.puntBase[i] != undefined) ? 
        this.config.puntBase[i] : '';
        let salCarte = (this.config.salCarte[i] != undefined) ? 
        this.config.salCarte[i] : '';
        let stockCar = (this.config.stockCar[i] != undefined) ? 
        this.config.stockCar[i] : '';
        let efec30a0 = (this.config.efec30a0[i] != undefined) ? 
        this.config.efec30a0[i] : '';
        let efec1a31 = (this.config.efec1a31[i] != undefined) ? 
        this.config.efec1a31[i] : '';
        let formExtr = (this.config.formExtr[i] != undefined) ? 
        this.config.formExtr[i] : '';
        let digitali = (this.config.digitali[i] != undefined) ? 
        this.config.digitali[i] : '';
        let deseSoci = (this.config.deseSoci[i] != undefined) ? 
        this.config.deseSoci[i] : '';
        let ro = (this.config.ro[i] != undefined) ? this.config.ro[i] : 
        '';
        let cab = (this.config.cab[i] != undefined) ? this.config.cab[i] 
        : '';
        this.objects.push(new DynamicTable(anio, puntBase, salCarte, stockCar, efec30a0, efec1a31, formExtr, digitali, deseSoci, ro,
        cab));
    }
    console.log(this.objects);
  });

}
```

Y para terminar la plantilla:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let items of objects; let i = index" class="punt-cab">
        <span *ngIf="i != objectKeys(items).length-1">{{items.cab}}</span>
      </th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let items of objects">
      <td  class="punt-comp">{{items.anio}}</td>
      <td  class="punt-comp">{{items.puntBase}}</td>
      <td  class="punt-comp">{{items.salCarte}}</td>
      <td class="punt-comp">{{items.stockCar}}</td>
      <td class="punt-comp">{{items.efec30a0}}</td>
      <td class="punt-comp">{{items.efec1a31}}</td>
      <td class="punt-comp">{{items.formExtr}}</td>
      <td class="punt-comp">{{items.digitali}}</td>
      <td class="punt-comp">{{items.deseSoci}}</td>
      <td class="punt-comp">{{items.ro}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Espero que te sirva, es un ejemplo, puedes mejorarlo lo que tu quieras.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let item of config.cab" class="punt-cab">{{item}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of config.anio">
      <td *ngIf="config.anio" class="punt-comp">{{item}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="config.puntBase" class="punt-comp">{{config.puntBase[i]}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="config.salCarte" class="punt-comp">{{config.salCarte[i]}}</td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

En este ejemplo se utiliza la directiva *ngIf para mostrar cada una de las columnas en función de si existen en el objeto config. Además, se está utilizando el índice i del ngFor para acceder a cada uno de los valores correspondientes en cada uno de los arrays del objeto config.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.